# Illustrate batch in Tensorboard using a generator

Tags: keras, tensorboard

I am using the keras and `fit_generator` to train my model. The current model I am doing is an auto-encoder - which does not render desired results. I would therefore like to create a callback that illustrates the training image and groundtruth image  in every 500 batch or so. I therefore want to use `on_batch_begin` I am however unsure of how I can access the current batch to create a `tf.Summary.Image`.

Can anybody direct me to some information about this or knows how to get the current batch. Or would it be done in the generator? I just do not see how to attach a callback to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not been able to find an elegant solution. I have added an array to the callback with the files I want to analyse. Then I randomly choose one image just for illustration, and use the current model and illustrate it on tensorboard. It works but I had hoped it would have been more elegant :)